# Performance Improvement for Real time Updates from RDS to Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, query-optimization, real-time-updates

As a part of an hourly process, we  source data from a table in RDS and ingest into the raw data layer Snowflake.

After ingesting, we have to update certain fields in the final mart table based on new data ingested.
This mart table is a very wide table with more than 100 fields and the size of the table is around 10 GB.

So these updates are taking 6-7 minutes.

Edit: Update Query  and Explain Plan:

```
update <target_table> tgt
set  email_id =src.email_id,
first_name = (
case
 when len(src.updated_first_name) < 2 then first_name
 when src.updated_first_name is null or src.updated_first_name = '' then first_name
 else src.updated_first_name 
end ),
last_name = (
case
 when len(src.updated_last_name) < 2 then last_name
 when src.updated_last_name is null or src.updated_last_name = 
'' then last_name
 else src.updated_last_name 
end),
link = src._link,
title = src.updated_title,
is_verified = 1,
last_verified = src.verified_time,
last_active_type_update = src.verified_time,
active_type = 'ENGAGED',                            
title_id = src.title_id,
function = src.function,
role = src.role
from <sourcetable> src
where lower(tgt.email_id) = lower(src.email_id)
and src.demographic_disposition in ('Updated Last Name','Updated 
Title','Updated First Name','Verified','Updated 
Country','Partial 
Verify')
and src.verified_time > '<last_runtime>';

Explain Plan:
     {
  "GlobalStats": {
"partitionsTotal": 728,
"partitionsAssigned": 486,
"bytesAssigned": 9182406144
  },
  "Operations": [
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "operation": "Result",
    "expressions": [
      "number of rows updated",
      "number of multi-joined rows updated"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "parent": 0,
    "operation": "Update",
    "objects": [
      "<target_table>"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "parent": 1,
    "operation": "InnerJoin",
    "expressions": [
      "joinKey: (LOWER(src.EMAIL_ID) = LOWER(tgt.EMAIL_ID))"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "parent": 2,
    "operation": "Filter",
    "expressions": [
      "(src.DEMOGRAPHIC_DISPOSITION IN 'Updated Last Name' IN 'Updated Job Title' IN 'Updated First Name' IN 'Verified' IN 'Updated Country' IN 'Partial Verify') AND (src.VERIFIED_TIME > '<last_runtime>') AND (LOWER(src.EMAIL_ID) IS NOT NULL)"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "parent": 3,
    "operation": "TableScan",
    "objects": [
      "<src_table>"
    ],
    "expressions": [
      "EMAIL_ID",
      "LINK",
      "UPDATED_FIRST_NAME",
      "UPDATED_LAST_NAME",
      "UPDATED_TITLE",
      "DEMOGRAPHIC_DISPOSITION",
      "VERIFIED_TIME",
      "FUNCTION",
      "ROLE",
      "TITLE_ID"
    ],
    "alias": "BH",
    "partitionsAssigned": 1,
    "partitionsTotal": 243,
    "bytesAssigned": 1040384
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "parent": 2,
    "operation": "Filter",
    "expressions": [
      "LOWER(tgt.EMAIL_ID) IS NOT NULL"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "parent": 5,
    "operation": "JoinFilter",
    "expressions": [
      "joinKey: (LOWER(src.EMAIL_ID) = LOWER(tgt.EMAIL_ID))"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "parent": 6,
    "operation": "TableScan",
    "objects": [
      "<target_table>"
    ],
    "expressions": [
      "EMAIL_ID",
      "FIRST_NAME",
      "LAST_NAME"
    ],
    "partitionsAssigned": 485,
    "partitionsTotal": 485,
    "bytesAssigned": 9181365760
  }
]
]
}
```

Now the new requirement is that this update jobs run every 5 minutes so that we can have near real time updated data in Snowflake.

However, we have tried all query optimisation  and are unable to bring the execution time of the updates to less than 5 minutes.

We are using a Small warehouse in Snowflake and due to budget constraints we cant increase it further to fasten the update query performance.

Is their any other budget friendly way to do near real time updates(after ingesting the data) in Snowflake?

Comment: Its difficult for people on forum to answer to such broad question. If you can share a sample query being used (perhaps a striped down version) it would make more sense. Updates in general are time-consuming but if its a key based update that will take less time.

Comment: HI can you please give us more information like the explain plain as it would give us information on how the query is executing.

Comment: Agree with Pankaj , on high level did you explored Streams and tasks options on RDS tables?

Comment: I have added the query and its explain plan and due to certain security constraints , object names have been made generic

Comment: We have a very similar setup and we use streams and tasks with MERGE. In general, we find it very fast but of course it depends on your data volume. If you are only concerned with newly inserted data then an insert only stream on your raw table should reduce the processing time as you only have the new data to scan and update